# Why the app Icon is not displayed in itunes?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, itunes, ipa

Hi Iam installing a application through iTunes, but when im adding the application(.ipa file) to iTunes its not displaying the app icon image and when I install the application into iPhone it is displaying the app icon image.

May I know where is the problem.

I want image to be displayed when I add the .ipa file to iTunes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add the iTunesArtwork icon file?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Note that this must be a 512 by 512 png image but its name is iTunesArtwork with no file extension.

Comment: Actually, I think now it's a 1024x1024 size image.

Comment: It hardly matters as this image is entirely in-house, as it were. Unless the 512 by 512 fails completely, but I don't think it does. The 1024x1024 is a different icon that will be needed when the app is submitted to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

If u get the ipa file from xcode and open it in itunes, it won't show the icon image in itunes, if you install it in ur iphone through sync with itunes, then the icon will be displayed.

This is the normal thing. Don't bother about that.

Comment: but other application wil show the icon image, then there should some problem ya..?

Comment: other applications means downloaded from app store or developed in xcode?

Comment: apps from appstore will show the icon in itunes, but build from xcode won't

Answer (score 0):

you have to add 76x76, 152x152, 40x40, 80x80, 29x29, 72x72, 154x154, 50x50, 100x100 and iTunesArtwork for see proper icon of app.

Answer (score 0):

App Icon naming iTunesArtwork(512 X 512) and iTunesArtwork@2x(1024 X 1024) should be added without image extention.